# optional export in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to export it conditionally. like below:

```
if(!flag){
    export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Game);
}
else {
    export default Game;
}
```

But in this I am getting an error:

```
Module build failed (from ../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level (677:4)
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export default flag ? Game : connect(mapStateToProps)(Game);
```